# Execute commands as another user

Tags: centos, sudo, users

I created a user named `intelmq` which has permissions to run a program called `intelmqctl`. Then I created a user named `apache` and I would like `apache` to execute `intelmqctl` as the user `intelmq`. I added the following lines to the `sudoers` file:

```
Defaults:apache !requiretty
apache ALL=(intelmq) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/intelmqctl
```

However, everytime I try to run the following command as user `apache` it the returns this:

command: `sudo -u apache sudo -u intelmq /usr/bin/intelmqctl --type json stop abusech-ip-parser`

output:

```
Sorry, user apache is not allowed to execute '/bin/sudo -u intelmq /usr/bin/intelmqctl --type json stop abusech-ip-parser' as apache on localhost.localdomain.
```

I'm using a CentOS 7.

Here are the steps that I made to install `intelmqctl` and the problem itself better explained, maybe I failed something during the installation: https://github.com/certtools/intelmq/issues/981

If I try to execute `sudo -iu apache` as `root`, it will change to the `apache` user, then if I execute the command `sudo -u intelmq /usr/bin/intelmqctl`, it works, it shows all the options to execute `intelmqctl`.

However, if I run the command `sudo -iu apache` as the `apache` user it returns: `Sorry, user apache is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash' as apache on localhost.localdomain.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59724/discussion-between-christophs-and-mf370).

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this problem?

Comment: @sebix Yes, the problem was on IntelMQ Manager when stopping the bots it wouldn't stop them and I tried via command line to replicate / find the solution using the user apache. But then I found out that the problem was from the soft kill command SIGINT, so I changed IntelMQ's code from SIGINT to SIGTERM.

Comment: @mf370 So this was [certtools/intelmq#981](https://github.com/certtools/intelmq/issues/981) and [certtools/intelmq-manager#103](https://github.com/certtools/intelmq-manager/issues/103). Will be fixed in version 1.1 (or current development branch).

Answer (score 0):

You can add setuid permission to that binary and change the ownership to intelmq.

```
chmod u+s /usr/bin/intelmqctl
chown intelmq /usr/bin/intelmqctl
```

Then you can run this executable with the process ownership of intelmq.

Comment: Correction: _Anyone_ can run the command with `intelmq` privilegies.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I must have added this information, my fault.

Comment: Thank you. However, those commands didn't solve the issue, it still returns the same output.

Comment: What you can do if you want to go this route is to copy the binary into a directory with read+execute only by the apache user. But this is a rather ugly solution.